# Is Shared Additional CSS slowing down the page loading speed? Should additional CSS be on specific/relative page?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

In my WP site (using mainly elementor), my developers put all of the Additional CSS in the Appearance-> Additional CSS.  Now there is 2230 lines of Additional CSS.  Is that normal or a definite issue?
For example if Additional CSS is specific to one page, should I make sure it is only connected to the one page.. ie.  if additional css is in "Appearance-> Additional CSS" is that loading for every page in the site, regardless if the code is not related to the page that is opening?

Comment: Do you use Elementor free or Pro?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is an issue.
Do you have access to the theme code?

If so,
Best practice would be to add conditional logic to run a stylesheet per page. Frr example:

```
if(is_page(id)){
  wp_enqueue_style()
}
```

You would need to break up your css in pieces and only run the pieces you need.